# VSTS - Customize Release Name Format

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to customize my Release Name Format to use the build id of my release artifact.
I tried using $(release.artifact._myartifact.buildid) but that is just seen as string. How would I achieve this?

I also tried to configure a group variable but this gave the same result.

Comment: [Variables in Release Mgmt][1]


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=powershell                                                                             
    Use -  Build.BuildId Same as - Release.Artifacts.{Primary artifact alias}.BuildId

Comment: I tried using $(Build.BuildId)-$(rev:r) but it is just displayed as string

Comment: That put me on the right track! I used $(Build.BuildNumber)-$(rev:r) and it worked. See reference for pre-defined variables in your link

Comment: @Dresse would be great if you shape it as an answer and accept it. This way it will help others facing with the similar challenge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution to my question on customizing the vsts release name format was found on following page under Primary artifact variables

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=powershell

The predefined variable Build.Buildnumber is the same as Release.Artifacts.{Primary artifact alias}.BuildNumber.
In my case I used  *$(Build.BuildNumber)-$(rev:r)* to get the desired result.

At first this was not working because I had multiple artifacts. Make sure you select the right artifact as primary artifact.

Comment: Really thanks for sharing your solution here, if possible, you could accept/mark your solution as an answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue find the answer easily. Have a nice day:)

Comment: Anyone know how to include pipeline variables (settable at release creation) in the release name?

Comment: the build number I want to use is of a container, coming from a second artifact, not the main artifact (main artifact has the release scripts, but what I want to call out is the container name)