# How to change custom release names in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, continuous-deployment

I want to change release names like `V.1.0.00` for manual release in Continuous Delivery of Azure DevOps but i can't able to delete or change the naming without this `$(rev:r)`, how can I use a custom name?

Default Name: `Release- $(rev:r)`

Required Name: `V.1.0.0`

Comment: Probably a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746260/vsts-customize-release-name-format

Comment: You may need to understand the `$(rev:r)` token first. To ensure that every completed build/release has a unique name. When a build/release is completed, if nothing else in the number has changed, the Rev integer value is incremented by one.  So, basically we cannot achieve that without using `$(rev:r)`, unless you can defined a token which has the same function with `$(rev:r)`.  You can try the the following solutions, they should did the trick.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62176262/pass-build-version-to-release/62176728#62176728 (you set the build id in your build and reference `$(Build.BuildId)` in your release name format.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the build Pipeline.

You can customize how your pipeline runs are named/numbered. Ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

In YAML, this property is called name.

Use variables to set your major version, minor version etc and generate  the patch version using counter Ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#counter.

for your case you can set
major : V.1
minor : 0
patch  : $[counter(format('{0}.{1}', variables['major'], variables['minor']), 1)]

and set the name like 
name: $(major_version).$(minor_version).$(patch_version)

Release pipeline

Refer to $(Build.BuildNumber) which will ref to the buildpipeline custom name/number set in the build pipeline.  You can change this naming scheme by editing the release name format mask. In the Options tab of a release pipeline, edit the Release name format property in the General page. Ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-manage-the-names-for-new-releases.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the naming scheme by editing the release name format mask.

When specifying the format mask, you can use the pre-defined variables mentioned in this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/index?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-manage-the-names-for-new-releases) or custom variable -- the value of a global configuration property defined in the release pipeline.

But for your issue ,as far as I know, no pre-defined variables can be displayed like V1.0.0 as release name.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. release name must be a **unique** name, therefore Azure DevOps requires you to put `$(rev:r)` in the name, because it's adding a incremental number for each release.

Another option is to use `$(Build.BuildNumber)` or `$(Release.ReleaseId)` that are also unique but is not will solve your issue.