# Pass Build Version to Release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How does one pass the build version (say v`1.2.3`) from an Azure DevOps Build Pipeline to/through the Artifact to the Release? Ideally we would like our build number (in package.json) to match the release name or rather our release name should reflect the build number/semantic version.

A manual solution where we enter the version number when creating the release is also acceptable. The release has a Release Name format which is set to `Parts-$(Build.Buildnumber)`. We can see no way to use custom values (entered at release creation) here. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch) is unclear on how to use these variables.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I discovered the answer.

1. Set the build name dynamically from your build script using the `##vso[]` directive as follows (in our case by readining `version` from `package.json`:

```bsh
$ver = (Get-Content -Raw ./package.json | ConvertFrom-Json).version
Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$ver"
```

2. Use `$(Build.Buildnumber)` in your release pipelines "Release name format".

Comment: StackOverflow: "You can accept your own answer in 9 hours"

Comment: I tried this and it shows the Release number not the build pipeline build number